# Why is my SELECT COUNT query not working?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
//creating a resultset + connecting with the connection method and typing in query
ResultSet rowCount = MainApp.dataBaseSelect("SELECT COUNT(isFoundStatus) FROM damageclaim");

//creating int variable but needs a value since in later row it says ' might not be initalized '
int rowCountInt = 0;

//giving the resultset to the int.
while (rowCount.next()){
    rowCountInt = rowCount.getInt("isFoundStatus");
}
//testing with system out
System.out.println(rowCountInt);
```

I wish to get the length of my database rows but it doesn't work for some reason, whereas other connections to the database do work.

Error I get: the column could not be found,  even though I truly have it...

Comment: "doesn't" work is not the proper description of a problem. Please tell us what exactly doesn't work and include all the necessary code in the question (for example the `MainApp` class).

Comment: I assume it works if you do it by index, like rowCount.getInt(1)? You should probably name the column in the query like "SELECT COUNT(isFoundStatus) as isFoundStatus FROM..." if you want to access it by name.

Comment: You assume that `count(isFoundStatus)` somehow automatically inherits the alias `isFoundStatus`, which is not the case (or at least not in the database you are currently using).

Answer (score 2):

Let's *presume* that you're using JDBC.  In that case, you're going to want to do one of two things:

1. Alias your column so that you can refer to it by name:

   ```
   select count(isFoundStatus) as total from damageclaim;
   // later on
   rowCountInt = rowCount.getInt("total");
   ```
2. Use a column index to get the first value instead:

   ```
   select count(isFoundStatus) from damageclaim;
   // later on
   rowCountInt = rowCount.getInt(1);
   ```